# A difficulty in understanding the last statement in the solution.

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory

The question and its solution is given below:

[image]

I did not understand the importance of the last line in the solution,could anyone explain this for me please? I thought that the solution ends after the first line.

Comment: You are correct, the last line is superfluous.

Comment: The last line says the same thing as you have been asked to prove.  If $\psi$ is an eigenvector of $BA$ (with non-zero eigenvalue) then $A\psi$ is an eigenvector of $AB.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second line simply emphasise that the statement is true even if we switch the order of A and B. Something that is understood from the first line anyway.